# Outlook email program will receive incoming text messages, but will NOT receive messages that have attachments or links...they get bounced back

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

Plain text message are sent and received fine, but messages sent that include an attachment (like a PDF file) or a link to a website is bounced back to sender as a mail error. Below is the error message sender receives:

```
===========================================================================================

  ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<brian@abcxyz.com>
    (reason: 550 5.0.0 output error)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to local:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 5.0.0 output error
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable (output error)

Final-Recipient: RFC822; brian@abcxyz.com
X-Actual-Recipient: RFC822; brian@xxxxxx.securesites.net
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.0.0 output error
Last-Attempt-Date: Fri, 8 Mar 2013 20:01:45 -0500 (EST)

 ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<brian@abcxyz.com>
    (reason: 550 5.0.0 output error)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to local:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 5.0.0 output error
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable (output error)

Final-Recipient: RFC822; brian@abcxyz.com
X-Actual-Recipient: RFC822; brian@xxxxxx.securesites.net
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.0.0 output error
Last-Attempt-Date: Fri, 8 Mar 2013 20:01:45 -0500 (EST)
```

Comment: Does this happen to all senders or does it depend on what domain or mail server they send from?  Does it depend on the size of the attachment?  Does it depend on whether the message is sent as plain text vs. HTML vs. rich text?  Is your mailbox possibly full?  Are these Microsoft articles [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284204), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895853) or [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232118(v=exchg.80).aspx) helpful?